# Is it possible to run the rootfs containing kernel and DTB files for a specific board using qemu

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, yocto, qemu

Our hardware vendor provides us the yocto based rootfs for a gateway device (ARM softfloat) as a tar file. This file includes kernel image and the DTB files for that board. Is it possible to run this rootfs with no or minimal modifications using qemu? I extracted the tar file and created a CPIO archive (kept kernel image outside) and tried this command :

```
sudo qemu-system-arm -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0,mac=52:54:00:12:34:02 -netdev tap,id=net0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no    -kernel boot/zImage  -initrd ../initramfs.gz   -machine versatilepb -m 2012
```

But it just showed blank UI window. Is this not possible?

Or do I need to ask our hardware vendor for a yocto build with MACHINE set as "qemuarm"?

Note: Its OK if QEMU is unable to simulate any hardware from the DTBs

Comment: What do you mean by run the rootfs? Do you want to run an application or check any port? What type of emulation are you after?

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unlikely that this will work to a sufficient extent. However, your hardware vendor is legally obliged to hand out the sources, and (given some jurisdictional nitpicking) also the the metadata layers used to build the rootfs. So instead of asking then for a favor, just ask for your rights and then build whatever you need to help your development/debugging needs.

NOTE: this might exclude sources to custom applications that they provide. If you intend to use such, it is up for discussion.